# HTML + jquery expand a table on click and hover actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found some code online but having hard time getting it to work. I want to expand the table by clicking of the collapsed header. I got it working by changing my table structure by removing `<thead>` 
and `<tbody>` tags but I need them. Here is the table code:

```js
 $('table tr:not(.header)').hide();

 $('.header').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('expand').nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100);
 });
```

```css
table,
tr,
td,
th {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr.header {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.header .sign:after {
  content: "\2B9D";
  display: inline-block;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.header.expand .sign:after {
  /*content:"\2B9F";*/
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='testclass'>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr class="header expand">
        <th colspan="8"><a style='text-decoration:none;'>Test Table <span class="sign"></span></a>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Data 1</b>
        </td>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td><b>Data 1</b>
        </td>
        <td>Data 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Data 2</b>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">Data 2</td>
      </tr>

      <th colspan="4" class="center">Data 3</th>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Data 4</b>
        </td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
        <td><b>Data 4</b>
        </td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Data 4</b>
        </td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
        <td><b>Data 4</b>
        </td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Data 4</b>
        </td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
        <td><b>Data 4</b>
        </td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I think it's an issue with my jquery but I am not sure what is going wrong. I also want to have some tables that expand when you hover over them, which I also got to work by removing `<thead>` 
and `<tbody>` tags for it I used this:

```
 $('.header').hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('expand').nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100);
    });
```

but it had an issue when I left the header area and the the table would collapse, so I could not use the expanded table area if the mouse left the header. 
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Well I can't see any row other than the `Test Table` maybe fix it up first?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, this is how the table looks like: http://i.imgur.com/LJdd43N.png  and it does have rows as far as I understand. And when you click on the red area of the table header it should collapse and expand the whole table and it does do it if the thead and tbody tags are removed.

Comment: click `run` on your posted code and you'll see nothing. So fix that up or we can't help you.

Comment: That's weird, because I can't even run table code from w3schools examples with this codesnipet tool, but my code does run on w3schools website code tester :(

Comment: try a jsfiddle instead next time.

Comment: Thanks, it does work in jsfiddle just fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want

```js
$('table tr:not(.header)').hide();

 /*$('.header').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('expand');
   $(this).parent().parent().find('tbody tr').toggle();
 });*/

$('.header').mouseenter(function(){ 
  $(this).toggleClass('expand'); 
  $(this).parent().parent().find('tbody tr').slideToggle(100); 
});
$('table').mouseleave(function(){   
  $(this).find('.header').toggleClass('expand'); 
  $(this).find('tbody tr').slideToggle(100);

});
```

```css
table,
tr,
td,
th {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr.header {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.header .sign:after {
  content: "\2B9D";
  display: inline-block;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.header.expand .sign:after {
  /*content:"\2B9F";*/
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='testclass'>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr class="header expand">
        <th colspan="8"><a style='text-decoration:none;'>Test Table <span class="sign"></span></a>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Data 1</b>
        </td>
        <td>Data 1</td>
        <td><b>Data 1</b>
        </td>
        <td>Data 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Data 2</b>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">Data 2</td>
      </tr>

      <th colspan="4" class="center">Data 3</th>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Data 4</b>
        </td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
        <td><b>Data 4</b>
        </td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Data 4</b>
        </td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
        <td><b>Data 4</b>
        </td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Data 4</b>
        </td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
        <td><b>Data 4</b>
        </td>
        <td>Data 4</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Well almost it does expand the table now, which is great :) but it expands all of the tables around it. in the full page I got 8 tables and upon the click they all expand now

Comment: Why thank you B. Desai :) it works like a charm. Sorry to be a pain, would you have any idea how to get the hover to stay while your in the body of the table. With your code this works now really well now but when I leave the header region the whole table collapses. 

`$('.header').hover(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('expand');
     $(this).parent().parent().find('tbody tr').slideToggle(100);
    });`

Comment: @user1031204 see edited answer is this what you want?